# How to horizontally align spans of different parents in HTML/CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to horizontally align the following spans "term" and "desc" horizontally. I could do this dynamically by setting the margin-left of "desc" to the width of the icon. However, I don't think that's an optimal solution because it would require JavaScript. Is there another way?

```html
<dl>
  <div class="list-item">
    <dt><span class="icon"></span><span class="term">A term</span></dt>
    <dd><span class="desc">A description</span></dd>
  </div>
</dl>
```

I already tried to use CSS grid and flexbox but didn't come up with a solution so far.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can horizontally align the "term" and "desc" spans without using JavaScript by using display: table, table-row, and table-cell CSS properties.

I think you'd want something like this:

```
.list-item dt {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.list-item dd {
  display: table-cell;
  margin-left: 10px; /* Add some space between term and desc */
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.list-item .term {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.list-item .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px; /* Adjust as needed */
  height: 20px; /* Adjust as needed */
  background-color: red; /* Just for illustration */
  margin-right: 5px; /* Add some space between icon and term */
}

.list-item div {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Here we set the display property of the dt and dd elements to table-cell, which makes them behave like cells in a table. We also set the display property of the parent div to table-row, which makes it behave like a row in a table.

By default, table cells align their contents vertically to the middle of the cell. We can use the vertical-align property to align the contents of the "term" and "desc" spans vertically to the middle of their respective cells.

Finally, we set the display property of the "term" span to inline-block, which allows us to apply the font-weight property to it. We also set the display property of the "icon" span to inline-block and give it a width and height, so that it takes up some space. We can then use the margin-right property to add some space between the "icon" and "term" spans.

You can adjust the widths and heights of the "icon" and other elements as needed to fit your design.

Hope this helps!