# How to make align text inside a description list with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a description list in HTML that has an icon inside it's dt element.

```html
<dl>
        <div>
            <dt><span class="ic"></span><span>Dt</span></dt>
            <dd><span>Desc</span></dd>
        </div>
    </dl>
```

Since this icon has a certain width, the spans of the dt and dd elements won't be aligned horizontally. How can I achieve horizontal alignment here? I've added a picture to describe what i mean.
[HTML Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn4BU.png)

I searched for a solution that uses either css flexbox or grid but didn't find one.

Comment: Before asking please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried using CSS ? Your example does not feature CSS code

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

*This is my response to the question asked earlier. I believe you're still asking the same thing: [How to horizontally align spans of different parents in HTML/CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75508863/21121257)

Yes, you can horizontally align the "term" and "desc" spans without using JavaScript by using display: table, table-row, and table-cell CSS properties.

I think you'd want something like this:

```
.list-item dt {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.list-item dd {
  display: table-cell;
  margin-left: 10px; /* Add some space between term and desc */
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.list-item .term {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.list-item .icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px; /* Adjust as needed */
  height: 20px; /* Adjust as needed */
  background-color: red; /* Just for illustration */
  margin-right: 5px; /* Add some space between icon and term */
}

.list-item div {
  display: table-row;
}
```

Here we set the display property of the dt and dd elements to table-cell, which makes them behave like cells in a table. We also set the display property of the parent div to table-row, which makes it behave like a row in a table.

By default, table cells align their contents vertically to the middle of the cell. We can use the vertical-align property to align the contents of the "term" and "desc" spans vertically to the middle of their respective cells.

Finally, we set the display property of the "term" span to inline-block, which allows us to apply the font-weight property to it. We also set the display property of the "icon" span to inline-block and give it a width and height, so that it takes up some space. We can then use the margin-right property to add some space between the "icon" and "term" spans.

You can adjust the widths and heights of the "icon" and other elements as needed to fit your design.

Hope this helps!